# Bash grep -P with a list of regexes from a file

Tags: bash, grep, pcre

Problem: hundreds of thousands of files in hundreds of directories must be tested against a number of PCRE regexp to count and categorize files and to determine which of regex are more viable and inclusive.

My approach for a single regexp test:

```sh
find unsorted_test/. -type f -print0 |
    xargs -0 grep -Pazo '(?P<message>User activity exceeds.*?\:\s+(?P<user>.*?))\s' |
    tr -d '\000' |
    fgrep -a unsorted_test |
    sed 's/^.*unsorted/unsorted/' |
    cut -d: -f1 > matched_files_unsorted_test000.txt ;
wc -l matched_files_unsorted_test000.txt
```

`find | xargs` allows to sidestep "the too many arguments" error for grep

`grep -Pazo` is the one doing the heavy lifing `-P` is for PCRE regex `-a` is to make sure files are read as text and `-z -o` are simply because it doesn't work otherwise with the filebase I have

`tr -d '\000'` is to make sure the output is not binary

`fgrep -a` is to get only the line with the filename

`sed` is to counteract sure the grep's awesome habit of appending trailing lines to each other (basically removes everything in a line before the filepath)

`cut -d: -f1` cuts off the filepath only

`wc -l` counts the result size of the matched filelist

Result is a file with 10k+ lines like these: `unsorted/./2020.03.02/68091ec4-cf04-4843-a4b2-95420756cd53` which is what I want in the end.

Obviously this is not very good, but this works fine for something made out of sticks and dirt. My main objective here is to test concepts and regex, not count for further scaling or anything, really.

So, since `grep -P` does not support `-f` parameter, I tried using the `while read` loop:

```sh
(while read regexline ;
    do echo "$regexline" ;
    find unsorted_test/. -type f -print0 |
    xargs -0 grep -Pazo "$regexline" |
    tr -d '\000' |
    fgrep -a unsorted_test |
    sed 's/^.*unsorted/unsorted/' |
    cut -d: -f1 > matched_files_unsorted_test000.txt ;
    wc -l matched_files_unsorted_test000.txt |
    sed 's/^ *//' ;
done) < regex_1.txt
```

And as you can imagine - it fails spectacularly: zero matches for everything.

I've experimented with the quotemarks in the grep, with the loop type etc. Nothing.

Any help with the current code or suggestions on how to do this otherwise are very appreciated.
Thank you.

P.S. Yes, I've tried pcregrep, but it returns zero matches even on a single pattern. Dunno why.

Comment: `tr -d '\000' is to make sure the output is not binary` is strange. Just don't use `-z`. Or use `-a`.

Comment: I know this is extremely weird, however without `-z` I get zero matches with any pattern, even though I already use `-a`

Comment: I haven't fully understood your problem, but if you want `-P` and multiline matching and `-f` option as well perform substitution, [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) is a good option... also, both GNU grep and ripgrep support recursive searching, so you can avoid `find` as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this which will be impossible slow:

```
find unsorted_test/. -type f -print0 |
while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do
     while IFS= read -r regexline; do
        grep -Pazo "$regexline" "$file"
    done < regex_1.txt
done |
tr -d '\000' | fgrep -a unsorted_test... blablabla
```

Or for each line:

```
find unsorted_test/. -type f -print0 |
while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do
    while IFS= read -r line; do
         while IFS= read -r regexline; do
             if grep -Pazo "$regexline" <<<"$line"; then
                  break
             fi
        done < regex_1.txt
done |
tr -d '\000' | fgrep -a unsorted_test... blablabl
```

Or maybe with xargs.

But I believe just join the regular expressions from the file with `|`:

```
find unsorted_test/. -type f -print0 |
{
    regex=$(< regex_1.txt paste -sd '|')
    # or maybe with braces
    # regex=$(< regex_1.txt sed 's/.*/(&)/' | paste -sd '|')
    xargs -0 grep -Pazo "$regex"
} |
....
```

Notes:

- To read lines from file use `IFS= read -r line`. The `-d ''` option to `read` is bash syntax.
- Lines with spaces, tabs and comments only after pipe are ignored. You can just put your commands on separate lines.
- Use `grep -F` instead of deprecated `fgrep`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. The way you're suggesting is the other way around: match each file against every regex, which is the compelte opposite of what I want, and yes, it would be exceptionally slow.

HOWEVER, the `IFS= read -r line` did the trick - my own code benefitted from it and now works just as I want it to! Thank you so much!